# Android - Display an image in ImageView for 10ms

Tags: java, android, performance, imageview

I'm trying to display a picture in an ImageView for a very short time to people's eye reaction. 
I wish i could show a picture for about 10ms... 20ms... 50ms

I tryed with :

Alpha Animation

```
final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(1);
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animation.setRepeatCount(1);
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

Handlers postdelayed

```
Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawable.interogation));
        }
    }, 10); //10ms
```

i also tryed with Thread Sleep

```
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawable.interogation));
```

The two first ones almost work, but the image is displayed for more than 10ms... i think it's most about 100ms

In the last case, the image is not displayed at all.I figured that in this case, the View is not refreshed as fast as i want.

How can display my picture for 10ms ?

SOLUTION :

based on the answer :

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();

frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank), 10);
frameAnimation.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), loadedImage),howLong);
frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.interogation), 10);
frameAnimation.setOneShot(true);

mImageView.setImageDrawable(frameAnimation);

frameAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a frame by frame animation with one frame consisting the picture to be displayed and other frame consisting of a blank transparent picture. Set duration for the picture frame to whatever ms of time your want. Running the animation will flash the picture once, provided you set android:oneshot="true" in animation list's definition.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: Glad to help. So, you used frame animation?

Comment: yep
It's indeed faster, but i think i cant go under 50ms this way :p
Any better idea ?

Comment: Not at the moment. I think this is the best we can do. How do you measure the the time anyway? :P

Comment: oh, it's just a feeling. Since half a second works well, i can compare with what i know :)

Comment: This might also depend on hardware. Better hardware may be able to perform better.